# 'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. vscode output

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Hello my name is John i got this get this error on the vs code output but on the terminal i don't get any messeges.

I tried to find a tutorial or an article on how to fix this issue but i did not find any thing.Then i tried downloading the newest version of python and set it as a interpreter but that did not fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

When installing Python, **PythonPath** will be added to environment variable by default.

If you open the shell before installation, all you need to do is close the shell and reopen it.

Answer (score -1):

Is your python installation correctly referenced in PATH ?

Have you rebooted your pc/shell after installing python ?

Are you sure that the executable is python and not python3.11 (or whatever your version is) ?

Is your vscode trying to run a syntactically correct command (python.exe if you're on windows) ?

Comment: Thanks for helping me out, i just needed to reboot my pc and it is now all working thanks for the help.